# Converting nested discriminated union expressions into strings

Tags: recursion, f#

I'm trying to express simple math expressions using discriminated unions. for example 1 + 2 * 3, which can be constructed from integer constants using binary operators. The expressions are modelled using the following F# declaration:

```
type expr = 
   | Const of i:int
   | BinOpr of a: expr * b:string * c:expr
```

the construct Const generates an integer constant and the operator is given as a string (example: “+”) when generating an expression using the constructor BinOpr.

Here are 2 representation of expressions using this model.

```
let b = BinOpr(Const(2), "+", Const(2))
let c = BinOpr(BinOpr(Const(2), "-", Const(3)), "+", Const(2))
```

I'm trying to make a function which converts these expressions to strings, for example with b as argument, the outcome should be 
"2 + 2"
or with c it would be "2 - 3 + 2"

I couldn't figure out how I'm going to work around this honestly and looking for pointers which can help me to figure out a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you have to perform an action on each case of a discriminated union, you should think `match ... with`. So you put this into a function

```
let print e =
    match e with
    | Const i -> ...
    | BinOpr (l, op, r) -> ...
```

Your type definition is recursive, though, so you'll most likely want a recursive function as well. To achieve this, add the `rec` keyword in front of `print`; i.e. `let print e` becomes `let rec print e`.

I hope this is enough to get you started.